# In twitter bootstrap, what is the difference between the navbar and nav pills?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I was going through the components of twitter bootstrap and I found that there are two separate sections of navigational components, one is the Navbar and the other is the Nav-pills/tabs etc.

Navbar seems to be very similar to nav-pills, can anyone please highlight the difference between them and when to use either one of them as the the documentation is not really clear about this.

**Navbar:**

> "To start, navbars are static (not fixed to the top) and include
>   support for a project name and basic navigation. Place one anywhere
>   within a .container, which sets the width of your site and content"

[image: Navbar]

**Nav-pills:**

[image: Nav-pills]

Taken from [the bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Navbar aims to be common to all pages of your site ("support for a project name" is the link to homepage) whereas nav pills may be a navbar specific to a page or a section.

Basically, navbar is unique and provides links to main parts of your site. Nav pills may provide internal links to your page anchors...

But this is your decision anyway, depending on your preferences for menu rendering.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.