# Nav logo not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been attempting to get the perfect nav bar for nearly 12 hours now and every time there seems to be another little issue i can't seem to figure out. In this particular problem, the logo won't sit inline with the rest of the nav items.

Any help is much appreciated.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6dprd1cp/

Also, when shrinking the window the nav items are not responsive, aka they do not wrap onto a new line to fit smaller screens.

Also, when i create a container-fluid and attempt to style the bg color very simply with another color, why does it not respond when targeting the second selector of "maincontent" in

```
<div class="container-fluid maincontent">
```

I think i have been looking at this for too long today. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refrain from asking multiple question in one post

Comment: Please move the code from jsfiddle to the snippet

Comment: Try this code for logo in same line .navbar-brand img { width: 50px; height: auto; margin-top: -15px; }
Explain the responsive layout how you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing bootstrap navbar elements.

[**Fiddle working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6dprd1cp/1/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Galaxies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Telescopes</a></li>
      <li>
        <a class="navbar-brand nav-image" href="#"><img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/07/11/794282_education_512x512.png" /></a> 
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Get involved</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Add this. Because, `padding-top:15px` is coming from bootstrap on image.

```
.nav-image img{
  margin-top: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Per the Bootstrap v4 website, what i have is acceptable. If you know more, please explain the difference to me.    https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#base-nav

Comment: Don't get confused between bootstrap `.nav` `.navbar`. [Both are different and works differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14022135/in-twitter-bootstrap-what-is-the-difference-between-the-navbar-and-nav-pills). **Navbar** is a wrapper that positions navigation, and other elements in a concise **header**. It’s extensible and collapsible (responsive behaviors). **Nav** may provide internal links to page anchors and it doesn't collapse automatically. **v4 nav** uses [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Looking back at the code, I see that i used both `nav` & `navbar` elements. What were you referring to as far as missing navbar elements?

Comment: Looking at your question. I made one more **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6dprd1cp/5/)**. `.maincontent` class with `.container-fluid` background-color. nav items are responsive now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the padding-top, but as it turns out `margin-top: -15px;` is the answer. Not sure what the difference in explanation is, but this is the selector the bootstrap.css addresses `.navbar-nav > li > a`, and this is what the solution looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Galaxies</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Telescopes</a>
        <div class="logo">
          <a class="navbar-brand custom-logo" href="#"><img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/07/11/794282_education_512x512.png" /></a>
        </div>    
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get involved</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</nav>
```

With this CSS:

```
.navbar {
background-color: transparent;
background: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
border-radius: 0;
display: flex;
margin: 0;
}
.nav {
display: inline-flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    height: auto; 
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 50px; 
}

.nav-link {
    margin-right: 2rem;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt1k5zyy/2/)